# Not able to use geckodriver on linux mint 18

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mozilla, geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import requests
import time

email = ""
password = ""

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I am using linux mint 18 and after running this above block of code , i am getting this error message

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quora_twitter_linkurl.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/bk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/bk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/home/bk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/home/bk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I am have tried all the solution but nothing is working for me.Please help me?

Comment: _Selenium Client_ / _WebDriver_ / _WebClient_ variant and versions please.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and selenium version 3.11.0 and geckodriver v0.20.1-arm7hf and firefox version 59.0.2

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium v3.x*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* you need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* indicating the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* binary as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Not working, i am using linux mint 18 and already tried this.

Comment: @BhupeshKurdia `Not working` doesn't throws any light oon whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current code and error stack trace.